# App doesn't build with two ToolbarItem

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to create a page in XAML with two ToolbarItems with differences between two platforms, but my app doesn't build. I have "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Here is my Page file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="VFood.Views.EntregadorEdit"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ToolbarItem">
            <OnPlatform.iOS>
                <ToolbarItem x:Name="SalvarItemIOS" Name="Done" Command="{Binding SalvarCommand}" Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>
                <ToolbarItem x:Name="RemoveItemIOS" Name="Trash" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" Order="Primary" Priority="1"/>
            </OnPlatform.iOS>
            <OnPlatform.Android>
                <ToolbarItem x:Name="SalvarItemDroid" Icon="ic_check" Command="{Binding SalvarCommand}" Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>
                <ToolbarItem x:Name="RemoveItemDroid" Icon="ic_delete" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" Order="Primary"  Priority="1"/>
            </OnPlatform.Android>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="8">
            <StackLayout.Padding>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"  Android="16,16,16,16" iOS="10,10,10,10"/>
            </StackLayout.Padding>
            <Entry Placeholder="Nome" Text="{Binding Entregador.Nome}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Telefone" Text="{Binding Entregador.Telefone}" Keyboard="Telephone" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

If I comment a toolbaritem for each platform, like the code below, the build works like a charm, but if I try build with the two toolbaritems, I have error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="VFood.Views.EntregadorEdit"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ToolbarItem">
            <OnPlatform.iOS>
                <!--<ToolbarItem x:Name="SalvarItemIOS" Name="Done" Command="{Binding SalvarCommand}" Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>-->
                <ToolbarItem x:Name="RemoveItemIOS" Name="Trash" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" Order="Primary" Priority="1"/>
            </OnPlatform.iOS>
            <OnPlatform.Android>
                <!--<ToolbarItem x:Name="SalvarItemDroid" Icon="ic_check" Command="{Binding SalvarCommand}" Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>-->
                <ToolbarItem x:Name="RemoveItemDroid" Icon="ic_delete" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" Order="Primary"  Priority="1"/>
            </OnPlatform.Android>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="8">
            <StackLayout.Padding>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"  Android="16,16,16,16" iOS="10,10,10,10"/>
            </StackLayout.Padding>
            <Entry Placeholder="Nome" Text="{Binding Entregador.Nome}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Telefone" Text="{Binding Entregador.Telefone}" Keyboard="Telephone" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (No one every said XAML was not verbose enough  )

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="SalvarItemIOS" Command="{Binding SalvarCommand}" Order="Primary" Priority="0">
        <ToolbarItem.Name>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Done"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Name>
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="Android" Value="ic_check"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="RemoveItemIOS" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" Order="Primary" Priority="1">
        <ToolbarItem.Name>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Trash"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Name>
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="ic_delete"/>
        </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Works like a charm and yes, what a verbose language hahaha